# Disabling orientation change with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, orientation

I need to fix the screen in landscape orientation at one point in my application, with the possibility to change back to normal. So far I have only seen suggestions of setting the orientation at launch time. I don't want to use Appcelerator for many reasons, and It should work on Android 2.2+ and Iphone.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS apps you can modify the project plist file (/Prject name/supporting files/Project name.plist). It will work.